# jquery, ajax: several post-requests instead of one

Tags: jquery, ajax, django-templates

I am using django and jQuery and I try to change button view after submit without page reloading. When I press it first time everything is okay, but the second press lead to two POST-requests, the third to three and etc and the button doesn't change anymore. Although data in databases changes as it should with every button pressing.

Please, help me to find out what is wrong with my jquery code and how prevent post requests multiplication

```
 function send()
{
    $('.valid').submit(function() 
        {
            var a_id = $(this).attr('a_id');
            var vl = $(this).attr('vl');
            $.ajax(
            { 
                        data: {'a_id' : a_id},
                        type: 'POST', 
                        url: 'vl/', 
                        success: function(data, status) 
                        { 
                            $('#mark_'+a_id).html('<i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i> Correct!')
                            $('#mark_'+a_id).attr("id",'cor_'+a_id);        

                            $('#cor_'+a_id).html('Not correct')
                            $('#cor_'+a_id).attr("id",'mark_'+a_id);

                        },
                        error: function(xhr, data) 
                        {
                            alert('fail: ' + data +' answer #'+ a_id);
                        }           
            });

        });

}
```

a_id is for answer id and it comes from button in template

```
{% if answer.validity %}

<button id="cor_{{ answer.id }}" class="btn btn-inverse js-mark " a_id="{{answer.id}}"  onclick = "send()" ><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i> Correct answer</button>

{% else %} 

<button id="mark_{{ answer.id }}" class="btn btn-inverse js-mark" a_id="{{answer.id}}" onclick = "send()" >Mark this answer as correct</button>

{% endif %}
```

The views.py part:

```
def question_vl(request, question_id):
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)

    if request.user == question.author:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if(request.POST.get('a_id')): 
                        a = Answer.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('a_id'))
                        if a.validity==False:
                    a.validity = True
                else:
                    a.validity = False
                a.save()
        return HttpResponse("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
$('.valid').submit(function()
```

attaches the submit event to the form. So whenever you press the button function "send" attaches the same event again.

Modify your buttons:

```
{% if answer.validity %}

<button class="btn btn-inverse js-mark" a_id="{{answer.id}}" onclick = "send(this)" ><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i> Correct answer</button>

{% else %} 

<button class="btn btn-inverse js-mark" a_id="{{answer.id}}" onclick = "send(this)" >Mark this answer as correct</button>

{% endif %}
```

Modify your function this way:

```
function send(button)
{
        button = $(button);
        var a_id = button.attr('a_id');
        $.ajax(
        { 
                    data: {'a_id' : a_id},
                    type: 'POST', 
                    url: 'vl/', 
                    success: function(data, status) 
                    { 
                        if (data.validity){
                           button.html('<i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i> Correct!')
                        } else {
                           button.html('Not correct!')
                        }     
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, data) 
                    {
                        alert('fail: ' + data +' answer #'+ a_id);
                    }           
        });

}
```

Your server side script should return JSON data with the actual value of "validity"

Comment: thank you very much!! this really prevents multiplication. but it raises some other problem: now the a_id is usually first button on the page so whatever button I press only first one changes. don't you know what is the problem?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. How many buttons and forms do you have on the page? If you have multiple forms it seems like you submit the first one every time. But i can only guess.

Comment: I have answer list under the question and every answer has a button used for marking answer as correct. I want to be able to press it several times so it would change like "correct"-"not correct"-"correct". So I tried to specify button id as "cor_"+a_id and "mark_"+a_id and change them every time, but now it seems that these don't work at all and I wonder is there a proper way of changing button appearance